# C: Sending float over UDP results in random symbols

Tags: c, udp

I have got a problem in my code which is supposed to send float numbers over udp. If I check my port incomings I just receive random symbols instead of my desired number.

```
printf("Lets send some cool data \n");
int clientSocket;

struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
socklen_t addressSize;

unsigned char   l_remoteHostAddr_rg4ui8[4]  = {192,168,22,160};
unsigned short  l_remoteHostPort_ui16       = 5000;
int             l_udpSocket_i32;
unsigned int    l_sendState_bl;

// open udp connection
l_udpSocket_i32 = g_halMatlab_initConnection_i32( l_remoteHostAddr_rg4ui8, l_remoteHostPort_ui16 );

halImu_orientationValues l_imuMeasurements_st;
g_halImu_initImuSensors_bl();

/*Create UDP socket*/
clientSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

serverAddress.sin_family = PF_INET;
serverAddress.sin_port = htons(REMOTE_PORT);
serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(REMOTE_ADDR);

memset(serverAddress.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(serverAddress.sin_zero));

/*Initialize size variable to be used later on*/
addressSize = sizeof(serverAddress);

printf("Start Sending Messages\n");

int i = kbhit();
while(i != 'q')
    {
        sleep(1);
        g_halImu_triggerImuReading_bl();
        g_halImu_triggerBaroReading_bl();
        g_halImu_triggerGyroReading_bl();
        g_halImu_triggerAccReading_bl();

        l_imuMeasurements_st=g_halImu_getImuValues_str();

        l_sendState_bl = g_halMatlab_sendImuState_bl(l_udpSocket_i32, l_imuMeasurements_st);

        printf("Acc X %f \n", l_imuMeasurements_st.acc.x_f64);

        float k = l_imuMeasurements_st.acc.x_f64;

        char imu_x[16];

        sprintf(imu_x,"%f \n",k);
        printf(imu_x,'\n'); //this prints the right number 

        sendto(clientSocket, imu_x, (int)sizeof(imu_x), 0,
               (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress,addressSize);
        printf("And send again....\n");
    }
```

If I know use nc -ul 5000 I receive 16 bit strings containing random stuff.

If anyone knows where my problem might be I would be really happy to hear from you

Have a nice day!

Comment: I suggest you should format your code properly.

Comment: You mean "16 character strings", right, not "16 bit strings"?

Comment: What are REMOTE_ADDR and REMOTE_PORT defined to?  The code to send UDP data is fine, but I suspect there's some confusion between `clientSocket` and `l_udpSocket_i32`, which appears to be where your sensor input is coming from.

Comment: sorry about the format.
REMOTE_ADDR and REMOTE_PORT are defined as constant
The numbers I want to send are sensor datas from hal/gyro over I2C from a raspberry

Comment: Not related, but `printf(imu_x, '\n')` should be `printf("%s\n", imu_x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **first problem** is that you are sending the same data two times. First through one socket called clientSocket and other other through another socket called l_udpSocket_i32. I am cleaning the code, so that only clientSocket is compiled.

Your **second problem** is that you are trying to print all the 16 data of imu_x. You should only print the written characters. I have added a new variable called written. Run this and you would not see any garbage.

```
printf("Lets send some cool data \n");
int clientSocket;

struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
socklen_t addressSize;
int written;
char imu_x[16];

halImu_orientationValues l_imuMeasurements_st;
g_halImu_initImuSensors_bl();

/*Create UDP socket*/
clientSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

serverAddress.sin_family = PF_INET;
serverAddress.sin_port = htons(REMOTE_PORT);
serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(REMOTE_ADDR);

memset(serverAddress.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof(serverAddress.sin_zero));

/*Initialize size variable to be used later on*/
addressSize = sizeof(serverAddress);

printf("Start Sending Messages\n");

int i = kbhit();
while(i != 'q')
    {
        sleep(1);
        g_halImu_triggerImuReading_bl();
        g_halImu_triggerBaroReading_bl();
        g_halImu_triggerGyroReading_bl();
        g_halImu_triggerAccReading_bl();

        l_imuMeasurements_st=g_halImu_getImuValues_str();

        printf("Acc X %f \n", l_imuMeasurements_st.acc.x_f64);

        float k = l_imuMeasurements_st.acc.x_f64;


        written = sprintf(imu_x,"%f \n",k);
        printf(imu_x,'\n'); //this prints the right number 

        sendto(clientSocket, imu_x, written, 0,
               (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress,addressSize);
        printf("And send again....\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`imu_x` is 16 characters long, but when you use `sprintf()` to put a float into it, it will only be only 7 characters. The space, newline, and trailing null add 3 more characters, but the remaining 6 characters in the string will be uninitialized, and that's probably the garbage you're seeing on the receiving end.

Instead of sending `sizeof(imu_x)` bytes, I suggest you send `strlen(imu_x)` bytes.

Comment: Im afraid nothing changed.
I should add, that the correct numbers arent even displayed.
GV>u5 �2����?��WOn�?�.*�%��� is the output instead of -0.050297. 
My printf(imu_x) shows the right number, thats what confuses me
Greetings =)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to incompletely defining the buffer sent ([@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37715277/2410359)), printing a `float` into such a small buffer can easily over flow.

```
float k = l_imuMeasurements_st.acc.x_f64;
char imu_x[16];
sprintf(imu_x,"%f \n",k);
```

Should `k` have the value of 1.2345, then `imu_x[]` will become `"1.234500 \n"` - at least 11 `char` are needed.  With `k` having a value like -12345, then the result will be `"-12345.000000 \n"` and 16 `char` are needed.  Easy to see how a slightly larger value will overflow the buffer.  Once that happens, the rest of code is **undefined behavior**.

---

Instead, recommend to clear the buffer and use `%e` when printing to provide significant data for the entire range of `float`.  Specify a width of 13 and 5 digits after the decimal point.  By using `snprintf()`, the buffer will not be overfilled.  By using a width of 13 (+3 for the space, \n and \0), the buffer will always print to the first 16 `char`.

```
memset(imu_x, 0 , sizeof imu_x);
// sign dig . digs e sign expo space \n \0
//  1    1  1  5   1  1     3    1    1  1
snprintf(imu_x, sizeof imu_x, "%13.5e \n",k);
```

Comment: Im afraid but i still receive the symbols.
T+GVH����N��?��WOn��:�}o�e%����r>��Hyzq�q۾ is what Im receiving.
Im wondering why I just receive this without even a sight of a number
Greetings=)

Comment: Post the code that shows 1) how code received the data 2) how code printed the data "T+GVH..."

Comment: @chux He said he's using the `nc` command to receive and print the data. http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc